# Ease of access to playlists on iOS 10

Tags: music, ios

I currently use iOS 9 on an iPhone SE. I frequently use the Music app to play a specific playlist of relaxing music before bed, so I like that from opening the Music app the playlists list is easily accessible. (The playlists tab is always on the bottom, unless a song is playing in which case I must minimize that first). And I can often bring up that particular playlist in the app so later when I go to the Music app it's right there for me to tap the first song.

My concern is with the Music redesign in iOS 10, which I have not personally used and is part of my reason to be hesitant about upgrading. My question is, how easy is it to access playlists (and other parts of the app, like artists or songs), and is it easy to open a playlist so it will be there for me next time I open the app?

Comment: Do you use Apple Music?

Comment: @books453 No music subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I have an iPhone SE on iOS 10, but my music is solely synced from iTunes, so I can’t speak for Apple Music playlists.

---

It should be relatively easy, Playlists is the very first option upon opening the Music app to your library:

[image: iPhone SE iOS 10 Music app home screen shot]

---

And you can easily have the playlist open while you listen to a song so you’re ready to hit play at a later time:

[image: iPhone SE iOS 10 Music app playlists screen shot]

---

As long as you don’t force quit the app its state will go unchanged and it'll show whichever part of the app you were on before hitting the home button when you reopen it.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I'm like you, sync music through iTunes and no Apple Music. So question, if I were in another view like Songs or Artists does it take a lot of taps to get to Playlists again?

Comment: @kal-al It does take a few taps. 2 to go into playlists, and a third one to choose a playlist.

Comment: Samething for Apple Music playlists.